# intellij idea no longer imports new gradle modules to my project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I am using a curriculum from a website called exercism.io, I used this about a year or 2 ago and when i would download the next "coding problem" to the project directory everything would work just fine and I was able to run the tests and whatnot. But now for some reason when I downloaded the next problem "allergies" the little blue square that normally shows in the lower right hand corner of the folder is not there, and consequently I cannot build or run the module or run any kind of gradle testing. Im not sure whats going on or if theres some kind of further setup I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Ok i figured out the answer for anyone who might be having this same issue. When importing the new module in module setting, I had to select use gradle wrapper, instead of the default, "use local gradle". It may just be that i've been out of the coding game for 1 year plus, and had only limited knowledge at that, but hopefully this is able to help someone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8sdD.png)